# Return intersection of generic types

Tags: java, generics, java-7

I would like to have a function return an object that is guaranteed to implement two interfaces. The exact object is not necessarily known at compilation time. My code looks something like:

```
class HelloWorld {

  public interface A {}
  public interface B {}

  public static class C implements A, B {}
  public static class D implements A, B {}

  public static <T extends A & B> void g(T t) {}

  public static <T extends A & B> T f(boolean b) {
    if (b)
      return new C(); // Doesn't compile
    return new D(); // Doesn't compile
  }

  public static void main(String []args){
    g(f(true));
    g(f(false));
    <what_should_I_write_here> x = f(<user_inputted_boolean>); 
  }
}
```

When trying to compile I get the following error:

> HelloWorld.java:13: error: incompatible types: C cannot be converted to T
>           return new C();
>                  ^
>     where T is a type-variable:
>       T extends A,B declared in method f(boolean)
>   HelloWorld.java:14: error: incompatible types: D cannot be converted to T
>         return new D();
>                ^
>     where T is a type-variable:
>       T extends A,B declared in method f(boolean)

This doesn't work because you can't return two different types from a function and `C` and `D` are different types.

Is there any way to get the above code to compile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding regarding type variables. When you declare a method like

```
public static <T extends A & B> T f(boolean b) { … }
```

you declaring a *type variable* `T` to which the *caller* may assign an actual type (or a type variable of the caller’s context). E.g., the caller may do the following:

```
class SomethingCompletelyUnknownToF implements A,B {}

SomethingCompletelyUnknownToF var = f(trueOrFalse);
```

which the compiler will accept, because the type `SomethingCompletelyUnknownToF` used for `T` by the caller of `f` fulfills the constraint that the type must implement `A` or `B`. Of course, this will fail at runtime, because neither `C` nor `D` are assignable to `SomethingCompletelyUnknownToF`. In fact, it is impossible for `f` to fulfill this expectation of returning a specific type that it doesn’t even know.

To summarize, a type variable is not a variable that the method may assign a type, a type variable is a placeholder for a type *chosen by the caller*.

So the method signature

```
public static <T extends A & B> void g(T t) { … }
```

makes more sense as whatever actual type the caller chooses for `T`, it will fulfill the method’s expectation of implementing `A` and `B` when being passed as parameter. Of course, `g` can not expect it to be either, `D` or `C`, as it might be a completely unknown type implementing `A` and `B`.

That said, there is no way in Java, to express that a return type extends two types (other than declaring a concrete type extending both). In case of `RandomAccess`, there is no need to bother anyway, as it has no consequences. Note that the JRE classes also never declare when a returned `List` is guaranteed to implement this marker interface. This is accommodated by never expecting it as parameter type either. Similarly, `Serializable` is never declared as return or parameter type anywhere.

Comment: Thanks. My problem started by wanting to declare a function as accepting only `RandomAccess` `Lists` because it is a compile time guarantee that the user won't use my function in a way that makes the runtime O(n^2). I don't want users to call my function by mistake in such a form. Currently I have a run-time check that the given list is instanceof `RandomAccess`. I want to change this to a compile time check. Unfortunately the list that is passed to my function is created by a second function. This function always returns a `RandomAccess List` but not always the same concrete type.

Comment: I’ve just seen the other question and I’ll add an answer there. Keep in mind that, as said in this answer, JRE classes don’t declare `RandomAccess` in return types, so e.g. the result of `Arrays.asList` would be rejected by your method when enforcing the property at compile time, despite the fact that it is appropriate and will implement `RandomAccess` at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with everything Holger says in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37965954/452775). But I'd like to add one thing, just because tricky types are so much fun.

I believe what you'd *like* to do is to have a *intersection* return type of `f`, like this:

```
public static A & B f(boolean b)
```

Then `f` would return some object which implements both `A` and `B`. This would make the return-statements of the method type check and you could assign its return value to either `A` or `B` variables.

But of course this is not allowed, intersection types in Java are only allowed on type variables.

You could try this:

```
public static Optional<? extends A & B> f(boolean b)
```

Here a intersection type is okay because it instantiates the type parameter of `Optional`. But this is not allowed anyway since wildcards can only have one bound, `&` can not be used.

---

**[Ceylon](https://ceylon-lang.org/)** is a very interesting programming language which has support for first-class intersection and union types. You could write the above examples in Ceylon.

Check it out, its *really* interesting!

Answer (score 0):

There is a little known feature called implicit bounds which allows this with a roundabout encoding:

```
interface MyGetter<R extends A> {
    R get(MyArgs foo);
}
private MyGetter<? extends B> getter;
```

This works because for wildcards the interface bounds are automatically added to the stated bounds. This lets you imply bounds that cannot be written down in java, including intersections, loops, infinite stacks of types, etc. It's a weird feature.

Anyway, `getter.get(args)` will return an anonymous type that is a subtype of both A and B.