# Object <? implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB>

Tags: java, interface, casting

I need a object who refers to two diffenrent interfaces like this:

```
interface InterfaceA {
    public void a();
}

interface InterfaceB {
    public void b();
}

class Test() {
    Object <? implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB>; object;

    Test() {
        object.a();
        object.b();
    }
}
```

I know for inheritance there is this way: `Class <? extends Main> a`  and a solution could be a helper class: `class Helperclass implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB{}`

Thanks for help and reading :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return intersection of generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835850/return-intersection-of-generic-types)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Generics Wildcarding With Multiple Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745756/java-generics-wildcarding-with-multiple-classes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add a generic type parameter to your `Test` class, you can require that this type parameter implement both interfaces:

```
class Test<T extends InterfaceA & InterfaceB> {
    T object;

    Test() {
        object.a();
        object.b();
    }

}
```

Of course you should initialize the `object` variable before calling methods.

Comment: Thank you. What should I do, If I need two or more generics?

Comment: @Nero If you mean two or more generic type parameters, you can define as many as you need. For example: `class Test<T extends InterfaceA & InterfaceB,R,S extends InterfaceB>`